# Getting SSL error "Unsupported protocol" when running in Visual Studio

Tags: browser, blazor

I am trying to build a Blazor application and I always get the following error :
"This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite."

My Chrome browser is up to date. I tried with Edge but the same error !
I tried the following link, too :
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-err-ssl-version-or-cipher-mismatch

Until a day all was working fine and I don't know what happened...
If I run the same application on another Windows 7 PC, it is working fine...
Can you help me, please ?
I will put here a screen capture :
[image]

Comment: [That's all](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/ssl-error-how-to-go-around-it/32935ffc-6844-4a2e-9c0f-52ba6b9b9d0d) I could find so far.

Comment: After Google Chrome updated to Version 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit),
none off my PC's is opening any blazor page ! This is almost 100% because of the update.
This is the error that I always get :

*This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.*

I installed Firefox and now I can run my project...
But I still want to know what can I do to run my project in Google Chrome..

Answer (score 7):

You can use firefox
Firefox: about:config "tls" > security.tls.version.min=1.  Reset to 3 after completion.

1. Install Firefox.
2. Type "About:config" in the address bar and hit return.
3. Click "Accept the risk" and continue.
4. Type "tls" in the search bar and hit return.
5. Click the pencil icon at the far right of "security.tls.version.min" to edit the cutoff setting prevening your login, which is currently 3.
6. Type "1" and hit return.

Comment: For accessing old hardware which is no longer being updated, this is gold.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same issue. Managed to get it sorted by downloading IIScrypto and enabling the Best practices TLS and Cipher versions.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me.

Working with VS19

Tried a lot of things such as:

- deleting localhost certificates,
- repairing IIS Express 10,
- clearing browser data and certificates cache,
- deleting .vs folder,
- allowing every TLS and SSL options in the browser

My .NET Core web apps are working under IE. So my guess is also that it's a Chrome update problem. But I haven't found how to fix that. :-(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This comment is more for other reviewers. While this doesn't answer the question with a specific working solution, and therefor is barely more than a 'me too' comment, it does provide what may be useful attempts at solving the problem (one or more of which might indeed work for others).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I work with Windows 7 Visual Studio 2019 browser chrome. The problem was solved in this way:
Open the project properties - debugging - uncheck the box "use SSL".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm discovering this now myself. The solution I've seen is to use Edge's internet explorer compatibility mode or use firefox. That seems to do the trick for me.